# How to know the parent chain of an object?

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object, which is another object's property, can I find the parent ?

```
A[a] = o
```

I have `o`, how to get the `A`? Further, if `A` is a property of `B`, how to find the chain?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Consider:

```
   foo = {}
   A.x = foo
   B.y = foo
```

who's the "parent" of foo?

However, if all "root" objects are known, you can find "parents" by walking the object tree recursively:

```js
scope = {}

foo = {"str": "hey"}

scope.A = { x: 1, y: { parent: foo }}
scope.B = { x: 5, zz: foo }


function findParent(what, where) {
    if(typeof where !== "object")
        return;
    var found;
    Object.keys(where).some(function(k) {
        if(where[k] == what)
            return found = where;
        return found = findParent(what, where[k]);
    })
    return found;
}

par = findParent(foo, scope);

document.write(JSON.stringify(par));
```

This code can be extended to find all "parents" instead of the first.